# How to present a different view controller only at first launch of iOS app (Swift) - programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Upon first downloading my app, I want to push a different view controller (such as a tutorial view controller), then after opened again, I want to push my normal view controller upon launching. In swift, the way I push a view controller is the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

So intuitively, maybe something like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    if firstRun == true {
        window!.rootViewController = LaunchViewController()
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        window!.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to save that state in `UserDefaults`

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LaunchedBefore") {
    window!.rootViewController = LaunchViewController()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "LaunchedBefore")
} else {
    window!.rootViewController = ViewController()

}
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Great! So apparently SO will only let me accept an answer after 15 minutes, haha. So I'll use this time to double check if I understand your code. So you create some boolean var, which is referenced by a key ("LaunchedBefore"), then after pushing the LaunchVC the first time, you change it's value to true, thus at the next launch, VC is pushed.

Comment: Also keep in mind default value of bool keys that doesn't exists in  `UserDefaults` is `false`

Comment: Right, I see. Thank you!